Novel. Parents drugged kid(s) to lower intelligence due to blackmail/threats. Attempts were made to kill/kidnap the kids when they were younger
Probably read 15-20 years ago. IT was a paperback in English, published in USA.
The story set when man has reached the stars. (Honor Harrington level of civilization.) I recall a bit of a story. I can't remember if the main character (MC) was male or female.
Something happens (attempt on life, or attack on family) and the parents tell the now adult children, they need to stop what ever they had been doing because it happened before.
It comes out that either the MC or their siblings had been drugged, (when they were early or mid teens) by either the parents or their enemies, with a drug that lowered intelligence. Maybe the family were royalty or big in politics and the drugging was a warning to stay out.
Maybe the parents were told, You feed this drug to the kids, and we won't try to kill them again? (Thus the parents will be too busy taking care of the kids to be involved in politics.)
I get a feeling that maybe an older brother had been drugged. (I'm not sure if the other kids were drugged.) I seem to remember him raging about, thats the reason why he had so much trouble in school, and the rest of extended family (aunts/uncles/cousins) were telling him he was stupid.
When the drugging stopped (or he became immune to the drug,) it took so long for him to catch up to his classmates who were now years ahead of him education wise.

When did you read this?  E-book, paperback or hardcover?

Hmm, for a minute I thought it might have been part of Vatta's War series, but a quick scan did not show anything. But it was that type of book or series I believe.

I suspect this is "Sporting Chance" (1994) by Elizabeth Moon (author of Vatta's War). The story involves a prince who had been drugged to make him less intelligent to avoid a risk to the king.

That would make sense. I kept feeling so strongly that it was in one of the Vatta's War series, (Kept thinking it might have been Rafe(?) The man who had the Gate control ability in his implants) but could not find anything even going through the books several times.  Will check it out and see if it is what I am thinking of.

Yes this is the book I was looking for. I was thinking of the right Author, but Wrong series when I looked for it. Thanks!
